# How we can add two date intervals in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, addition, dateinterval

i want to add two date intervals to calculate the total duration in hours and minutes in fact i want to perform addittion as shown below:

```
$a = new DateTime('14:25');
$b = new DateTime('17:30');
$interval1 = $a->diff($b);
echo "interval 1 : " . $interval1->format("%H:%I");
echo "<br />";

$c = new DateTime('08:00');
$d = new DateTime('13:00');
$interval2 = $c->diff($d);
echo "interval 2 : " . $interval2->format("%H:%I");
echo "<br />";

echo "Total interval : " . $interval1 + $interval2;
```

Any idea how to perform this type of interval addition to get the sum of the two intervals in total hours and minutes format in PHP

Answer (score 50, accepted):

PHP has no operator overloading* so `+` with objects makes PHP trying it to convert them to string first, but `DateInterval` does not support that:

```
interval 1: 03:05
interval 2: 05:00
Total interval : 08:05
```

Instead you need to create a new `DateTime` object, then use the `add` function to add the intervals and finally display the difference to the reference point:

```
$e = new DateTime('00:00');
$f = clone $e;
$e->add($interval1);
$e->add($interval2);
echo "Total interval : ", $f->diff($e)->format("%H:%I"), "\n";
```

Full Example/([Demo](https://3v4l.org/J9iGJ)):

```
$a = new DateTime('14:25');
$b = new DateTime('17:30');
$interval1 = $a->diff($b);
echo "interval 1: ", $interval1->format("%H:%I"), "\n";

$c = new DateTime('08:00');
$d = new DateTime('13:00');
$interval2 = $c->diff($d);
echo "interval 2: ", $interval2->format("%H:%I"), "\n";

$e = new DateTime('00:00');
$f = clone $e;
$e->add($interval1);
$e->add($interval2);
echo "Total interval : ", $f->diff($e)->format("%H:%I"), "\n";
```

---

You might also want to consider looking how `DateInterval` stores its' values and then extend from it to do the calculation your own. The following example ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BcOh2)) is rough, it does not take into account [the inverted thingy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert), it does [not (re)set `$days` to `false`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days) and I have not checked/tested the ISO specification of [the period specifier on creation](http://php.net/manual/dateinterval.construct.php) but I think it is enough to show the idea:

```
class MyDateInterval extends DateInterval
{
    /**
     * @return MyDateInterval
     */
    public static function fromDateInterval(DateInterval $from)
    {
        return new MyDateInterval($from->format('P%yY%dDT%hH%iM%sS'));
    }
                                  
    public function add(DateInterval $interval)
    {
        foreach (str_split('ymdhis') as $prop)
        {
            $this->$prop += $interval->$prop;
        }
    }
}

$a = new DateTime('14:25');
$b = new DateTime('17:30');
$interval1 = $a->diff($b);
echo "interval 1: ", $interval1->format("%H:%I"), "\n";

$c = new DateTime('08:00');
$d = new DateTime('13:00');
$interval2 = $c->diff($d);
echo "interval 2: ", $interval2->format("%H:%I"), "\n";
                                  
$e = MyDateInterval::fromDateInterval($interval1);
$e->add($interval2);
echo "Total interval: ", $e->format("%H:%I"), "\n";
```

---

<sup>*</sup> If you write a PHP extension, it actually is possible (at least sort-of).

Comment: Some more experiments: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Lh2DtL ([gist](https://gist.github.com/3142405))

Comment: Hi, what if, with your solution, the total is greater than 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 24 hours, ... etc ? :)

Comment: @Talus: See the gist, not that it is perfect, but it shows how you can handle that.

Comment: Yup, I was refering to the last snippet (the extension of the `DateInterval`) you posted. But the first snippet (when you add / substract the intervals and then calculated the diff) was what I did, and this works pretty well :)

Comment: My answer is not totally correct, for example with some DateTime classes you can actually use the + operator.

Comment: I used this for now and created a request for the PHP core to add a new method to the DateInterval class: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/390

Comment: Wow, that's pretty nice Simon! Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: I basically did what you showed in the second code block. But pumped a `\DateInterval('P135DT15H14M')` type object into the add method. Since the intervals I am working with are not date specific, this worked perfectly for solving my problem of getting total hours between two of those styles of date intervals (these are cumulative hours). Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't ``return new DateInterval()...`` format be ``P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS``? The provided format misses months...

Answer (score 9):

This function allows you to combine any number of DateIntervals

```
/**
 * Combine a number of DateIntervals into 1 
 * @param DateInterval $...
 * @return DateInterval
 */
function addDateIntervals()
{
    $reference = new DateTimeImmutable;
    $endTime = clone $reference;

    foreach (func_get_args() as $dateInterval) {
        $endTime = $endTime->add($dateInterval);
    }

    return $reference->diff($endTime);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, `$endTime` I think because of the `DateTimeImmutable`. Worked when I changed `new DateTimeImmutable` for `new DateTime()`

Comment: @Gyfis Strange, it works just fine for me. Remember that Immutables will return a new instance when changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare_dateInterval($interval1, $operator ,$interval2){
    $interval1_str = $interval1->format("%Y%M%D%H%I%S");
    $interval2_str = $interval2->format("%Y%M%D%H%I%S");
    switch($operator){
        case "<":
            return $interval1 < $interval2;
        case ">":
            return $interval1 > $interval2;
        case "==" :
            return $interval1 == $interval2;
        default:
            return NULL;
    }
}
function add_dateInterval($interval1, $interval2){
    //variables
    $new_value= [];
    $carry_val = array(
                    's'=>['value'=>60,'carry_to'=>'i'],
                    'i'=>['value'=>60,'carry_to'=>'h'],
                    'h'=>['value'=>24,'carry_to'=>'d'],
                    'm'=>['value'=>12,'carry_to'=>'y']
                );

    //operator selection
    $operator = ($interval1->invert == $interval2->invert) ? '+' : '-';

    //Set Invert
    if($operator == '-'){
        $new_value['invert'] = compare_dateInterval($interval1,">",$interval2)?$interval1->invert:$interval2->invert;
    }else{
        $new_value['invert'] = $interval1->invert;
    }

    //Evaluate
    foreach( str_split("ymdhis") as $property){
        $expression = 'return '.$interval1->$property.' '.$operator.' '.$interval2->$property.';';
        $new_value[$property] = eval($expression);
        $new_value[$property] = ($new_value[$property] > 0) ? $new_value[$property] : -$new_value[$property];
        }

    //carry up
    foreach($carry_val as $property => $option){
        if($new_value[$property] >= $option['value']){
            //Modulus
            $new_value[$property] = $new_value[$property] % $option['value'];
            //carry over
            $new_value[$option['carry_to']]++;
        }
    }

    $nv = $new_value;
    $result = new DateInterval("P$nv[y]Y$nv[m]M$nv[d]DT$nv[h]H$nv[i]M$nv[s]S");
    $result->invert = $new_value['invert'];
    return $result;
}

$a = new DateTime('00:0');
$b = new DateTime('17:30');
$interval1 = $a->diff($b);
echo "interval 1: ", $interval1->format("%H:%I"), "<br>";

$c = new DateTime('08:01:00');
$d = new DateTime('13:30:33');
$interval2 = $c->diff($d);
echo "interval 2: ", $interval2->format("%H:%I"), "<br>";

$addition = add_dateInterval($interval1,$interval2);
echo "<pre>";
echo var_dump($addition);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. I solve it for my case by creating a new `stdClass`, this object emulates a `DateInterval` object, however it is not a real `DateInterval` object. Then I looping over every real `DateInterval` while performing an compound assignment operation (for example `+=`) on the desired property. See below:

```
$dateTimeA = new DateTime('-10 day');
$dateTimeB = new DateTime('-8 day');
$dateTimeC = new DateTime('-6 day');
$dateTimeD = new DateTime('-4 day');

$intervalA = date_diff($dateTimeA, $dateTimeB);
$intervalB = date_diff($dateTimeC, $dateTimeD);

$intervalC = new StdClass; // $intervalC is an emulation of DateInterval 
$intervalC->days = 0;

foreach([$intervalA, $intervalB] as $interval) {
    $intervalC->days += (int)$interval->format('%d');
}


var_dump($intervalC);
/*
object(stdClass)[7]
  public 'days' => int 4
*/
```