# Summing time in DateTime() objects

Tags: php

I have an array of DateTime() objects in which I store some time duration (like "H:i")
How can I sum all elements in this array to get total time duration?

And it's also should be taken into account, that if total time duration is grater that 23:59, I have to be able to get nubmer of days.

is this possible?

I was trying to do like this:

```
$duration = new DateTime('00:00');

foreach($routes as $route) {
   $arrival_time = new DateTime();
   $arrival_time->setTimestamp($route->arrival_time);

   $departure_time = new DateTime();
   $departure_time->setTimestamp($route->departure_time);

   $leg_duration = $arrival_time->diff($departure_time);
   $duration->add($leg_duration);
}
```

but in `$duration` I got wrong time.

**P.S.**

Using `$duration->add($leg_duration);` I got subtracted from `"24:00"` time, why?
For example if `$leg_duration = new DateTime('02:10');` the result will be `"21:50"`.

`$duration->sub($leg_duration);` add time to `"24:00"`

Is this right?

Comment: yes, try it and post the code here if you run into trouble

Comment: You mean DateInterval objects? Summing up DateTime objects doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Ejay done, now is your turn.

Comment: This may prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556731/how-we-can-add-two-date-intervals-in-php

Comment: It might also be worth reading about [DateInterval](http://uk1.php.net/DateInterval)

Comment: if you're storing a proper datetime format field in the database / pulling details from a db rather than userinput then you can do all of this in an sql query by using min() and max() and date_diff()

Answer (score 1):

Concerning part of the question: you're using the `diff()` method in the inverted way, the code should actually be:

```
$leg_duration = $departure_time->diff($arrival_time);
```

Because in your code you are calculating $departure_time - $arrival_time (which is negative, thus giving you this "inverted" result).

Concerning the addition of time intervals, as a DateTime object contains a date too, you might have to do something like this to get a meaningful result:

```
$start = new DateTime('00:00');
$duration = $start;

// ...  your loop ...

$total = $start->diff($duration);
```

`$total` will be a DateInterval object, whose fields should contain your total time difference (although I didn't test this).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sum_the_time('01:45:22', '17:27:03');
```

this will give you a result:

> 19:12:2

```
function sum_the_time($time1, $time2) {
  $times = array($time1, $time2);
  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
  }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds); // Thanks to Patrick
}
```

I found from [here](https://vasavaa.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/sum-time-with-format-hhmmss-by-using-php/)