# Multiplication of a time in PHP

Tags: php, time

I need multiplication of time in PHP

```
$maritime ='01:10:00';
```

I need increment this `$maritime`  in to 5 
I want to  get answer like this

```
01:10:00*5 =  05:50:00
```

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: yes, i got adding two time function in php , but can't get any multiplication function

Comment: What you expect the result as for `01:10:00` ?

Comment: these time are taken from in mysql table with time format

Comment: If you want to do this with date intervals, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556731/how-we-can-add-two-date-intervals-in-php for ideas and code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what you should do

**Step 1 :** Convert your hours into seconds

```
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $maritime UTC");
```

**Step 2 :** Multiply it directly

```
$multiply = $seconds * 5;
```

**Step 3 :** Convert the seconds back to hours, And you're done !

```
echo gmdate("d H:i:s",$multiply);
```

**So Your final code shall be**

```
<?php
$maritime ='01:10:00';
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $maritime UTC");
$multiply = $seconds * 5;  #Here you can multiply with your dynamic value
echo gmdate("d H:i:s",$multiply);
```

Here is the [Link of Eval](https://eval.in/373216) which shows the Output

**Update :**

If you work with more than one day

i.e., time * 25 times, then it will have more than one day

Then my output will be `02 05:10:00`

But if you want it in hours strictly you should use the `DateTime`

```
<?php
$maritime ='01:10:00';
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $maritime UTC");
$multiply = $seconds * 25;  #Here you can multiply with your dynamic value
$seconds = $multiply;
$zero    = new DateTime("@0");
$offset  = new DateTime("@$seconds");
$diff    = $zero->diff($offset);
echo sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $diff->days * 24 + $diff->h, $diff->i, $diff->s);
?>
```

Here is the [Eval Link](https://eval.in/373224)

Comment: Yeah, that's a better solution than mine.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Well try it with the multiplier 25 and it doesn't work

Comment: With the same value `01:10:00` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Yes see: https://eval.in/373221 (<- with the comment of the expected output)

Comment: @Rizier123 Is't this value `02 05:10:00` means **2**nd day **5 hour and 10 minutes** which is  `29:10:00` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen But it doesn't output 29:10:00

Comment: Thanks all.. you all save my day

Answer (score 4):

Just convert the time to base unit (seconds in this case), then multiply it and convert it back.

Here is a quick example of how to do it, note that there is no error checking in `toSeconds` and you'll probably want to handle 00 in `fromSeconds`.

```
function toSeconds($time){
  $arr = explode(":", $time);
  return $arr[0]*3600 + $arr[1]*60 + $arr[2];
}

function fromSeconds($seconds){
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  return "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Try this

```
$your_time = "01:10:00";
date_default_timezone_set ("UTC");
$secs = strtotime($your_time ) - strtotime("00:00:00");
echo date("H:i:s",$secs * 5);
```