# PHP adding two DateInterval-objects together

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I'm crunching some numbers from a time recording experiment using PHP. How do I add two DateInterval-objects together?

One of the DateIntervals are found as such (the difference between two DateTime-objects):

```
$start_stamp = new \DateTime( '2017-09-01T07:10' ); // DateTime-object
$end_stamp   = new \DateTime( '2017-09-01T07:10' ); // DateTime-object
$duration    = $start_stamp->diff( $end_stamp ); // DateInterval-object
```

The other DateInterval is simply define as such:

```
$abc = new \DateInterval( 'PT1H' ); // DateInterval with duration of 1 hour
```

I've read a couple of [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556731/how-we-can-add-two-date-intervals-in-php), that one should convert my DateIntervals to DateTime-objects and then use the `$dateTimeObject->add(...)`-function. But that seems silly to me. It is a duration, - so why should I convert it to something that it isn't is, in order to handle it properly.

I wrote below-written function to solve the problem, - but it seems clumsy. Can it be written better - or are there a better way of summing up two DateInterval-objects?

```
function sumDateIntervals($dateinterval_one, $dateinterval_two)
{
  $d1_years = $dateinterval_one->y;
  $d1_months = $dateinterval_one->m;
  $d1_days = $dateinterval_one->d;
  $d1_hours = $dateinterval_one->h;
  $d1_minutes = $dateinterval_one->i;
  $d1_seconds = $dateinterval_one->s;
  $d1_float = $dateinterval_one->f;

  $d2_years = $dateinterval_two->y;
  $d2_months = $dateinterval_two->m;
  $d2_days = $dateinterval_two->d;
  $d2_hours = $dateinterval_two->h;
  $d2_minutes = $dateinterval_two->i;
  $d2_seconds = $dateinterval_two->s;
  $d2_float = $dateinterval_two->f;

  $return_dateinterval = new DateInterval( 
                     'P' . ( string ) ( $d1_years + $d2_years ) . 'Y' 
                     . ( string ) ( $d1_months + $d2_months ) . 'M' 
                     . ( string ) ( $d1_days + $d2_days ) . 'DT' 
                     . ( string )  ($d1_hours + $d2_hours ) . 'H' 
                     . ( string ) ( $d1_minutes + $d2_minutes ) . 'M' 
                     . ( string ) ($d1_seconds + $d2_seconds ) . 'S' );

  return $return_dateinterval;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2021 Update

Almost four years wiser, I think the best way is to let PHP compute the sum and normalize the fields in the process:

```php
function sumDateIntervals(DateInterval $a, DateInterval $b)
{
  $base = new DateTimeImmutable();

  return $base->add($a)->add($b)->diff($base);
}
```

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##bY4/C4MwEMX3fIoMBiNUqBUp2H@Lgw6FQrt0jHpBwUSJSTuUfnYbqkJLO927937cu67qhmF76KoOcSMLXbcS90YkTEMmNagba3r6uWGHLfC3kXvogbCdrAe8wxLub@BSC8iEMJrlDVBvYxEF2ig5kv6elSV1mDeJ3Iqy5py@U4s/EXIU9KbR9ujPT3PL7FD3FETHILkE6zRcnl1vgf8gK5tHaRjZ3DYgKKqWTiX@nrdKME1dkvjk6JMrJmlMspiM8DC8AA).

### The originally accepted answer

> To me, your solution looks like the best way to implement this functionality.
>
> There is no need to explicitly convert the sums to strings (PHP does it anyway). If you want to make it more readable you can use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to produce the string and shorter names for the arguments:
>
> ```
> function sumDateIntervals(DateInterval $a, DateInterval $b)
> {
>     return new DateInterval(sprintf('P%dY%dM%dDT%dH%dM%dS',
>         $a->y + $b->y,
>         $a->m + $b->m,
>         $a->d + $b->d,
>         $a->h + $b->h,
>         $a->i + $b->i,
>         $a->s + $b->s
>     ));
> }
> ```

Comment: There is a problem with this as recently as PHP8.

There is no overflow built-into this so it will make nonsensical and hard to reason about ISO DateIntervals. Try `var_dump(sumDateIntervals(new DateInterval('P0DT30S'), new DateInterval('P0DT30S')));`, which I would expect to come back with `P0Y0M0DT0H1M0S` instead it comes back with `P0Y0M0DT0H0M60S`, which might be equivalent, but imagine any where time-component S or M are both > 30, H are both > 12. Also think about Days, Months, Years. It's a difficult one to solve well I think.

Comment: It always worked this way: https://3v4l.org/9tCkj#focus=eol

Comment: It's not if it works, but what burden such DateInterval input strings have on a reviewer, troubleshooting engineer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to use the magic `__set_state()` method to create a new DateInterval, building an array of the property values that are needed from the sums of the equivalent properties in the two existing intervals.

A quick and ugly block of code (untested) to demonstrate this approach:

```
$properties = ['y' => PHP_INT_MAX,'m' => 12,'d' => 30,'h' => 24,'i' => 60,'s' => 60];


$dti1 = new DateInterval('P1Y7M16DT15H30M15S');
$dti2 = new DateInterval('P2Y8M26DT14H40M55S');

$state = array_fill_keys(array_keys($properties), null);

$carry = 0;
foreach(array_reverse($properties) as $property => $limit) {
    $state[$property] = $dti1->{$property} + $dti2->{$property} + $carry;
    $carry = 0;
    if ($state[$property] > $limit) {
        do {
            $state[$property] -= $limit;
            ++$carry;
        } while ($state[$property] > $limit);
        $state[$property] = $state[$property] % $limit;
    }
}

$newInterval = DateInterval::__set_state($state);

var_dump($newInterval);
```

It needs a bit of cleaning up to handle the `day` property, and to allow for the `f` property that was added in PHP 7.1

Comment: Hmm... This seems quite advanced. There are several things that I don't quite get. What's the advantage of doing it this way over the way that I suggested?

Comment: There aren't necessarily advantages, just a different approach.... although the `limit` logic tries to keep individual property values within an appropriate range, so you don't get (for example) `PT47H` but `P1DT23H`