# How calculate the sum of two DateInterval object

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference

I have two date interval object, is there any default method to add those interval object ?

```
$date1 = date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2 = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff_1=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff_1->format("%y years").' '.$diff_1->format("%m months"). ' ' . $diff_1->format("%d days");
//0 years 8 months 27 days

$date3 = date_create("2015-02-15");
$date4 = date_create("2015-12-12");
$diff_2=date_diff($date3,$date4);
echo $diff_2->format("%y years").' '.$diff_2->format("%m months"). ' ' . $diff_2->format("%d days");
//0 years 9 months 27 days
```

> `$diff_1+$diff_2` = 1 year 6 months 24 days

What i need is to calculate the sum of `diff_1` and `diff_2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How we can add two date intervals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556731/how-we-can-add-two-date-intervals-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably easiest way is to create a new object and cloning it, adding the two (or more) DateTimeIntervals (in your case `$diff_1` and `$diff_2`) to the new object. By now finding the difference between the new object and its clone, is the sum of the two DateTimeIntervals you originally had.

```
// Define two intervals
$date1 = date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2 = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff_1 = date_diff($date1,$date2);

$date3 = date_create("2015-02-15");
$date4 = date_create("2015-12-12");
$diff_2 = date_diff($date3,$date4);


// Create a datetime object and clone it
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt_diff = clone $result;

// Add the two intervals from before to the first one
$dt->add($diff_2);
$dt->add($diff_1);

// The result of the two intervals is now the difference between the datetimeobject and its clone
$result = $dt->diff($dt_diff);
var_dump($result);
```

Result of the dump includes

```
  ["y"]=>
    int(1)
  ["m"]=>
    int(6)
  ["d"]=>
    int(21)
```

..which is 1 year, 6 months and 21 days.

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/ieiBb)

**Sidenote**
You don't have to concat so many different formats with your `format()`. You can do it all in a single line,

```
echo $result->format("%y years %m months %d days");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add both `DateInterval` objects to a new `DateTime` object, and compute the difference again.

```
<?php

$date1 = date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2 = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff_1=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff_1->format("%y years").' '.$diff_1->format("%m months"). ' ' . $diff_1->format("%d days");
//0 years 8 months 27 days

$date3 = date_create("2015-02-15");
$date4 = date_create("2015-12-12");
$diff_2=date_diff($date3,$date4);
echo $diff_2->format("%y years").' '.$diff_2->format("%m months"). ' ' . $diff_2->format("%d days");
//0 years 9 months 27 days

$today = new DateTime();
$today->add($diff_1);
$today->add($diff_2);
$diff_total = $today->diff(new DateTime());

echo $diff_total->format("%y years").' '.$diff_total->format("%m months"). ' ' . $diff_total->format("%d days");
```

Comment: By not cloning `$today`, you can potentially end up with a slight difference. Could change the result in some obscure cases.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$date1 = new DateTime();
sleep(2);
$date2 = new DateTime();
sleep(1);
$date3 = new DateTime();
sleep(3);
$date4 = new DateTime();

$intervals = [
    $date1->diff($date2),
    $date2->diff($date3),
    $date3->diff($date4),
];

$reverenceTime = new DateTime();
$totalInterval = clone $reverenceTime;
foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
    $totalInterval->add($interval);
}

$sum = $reverenceTime->diff($totalInterval);
echo sprintf('%sh %sm %ss', $sum->h, $sum->i, $sum->s);
```

Output:

```bash
0h 0m 6s
```